# Javascript search in Json

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, web

I am totally new to Javascript and I have a small problem here.
When I am trying to get from Element value it works correctly(console shows value fine), but when I am trying to add this variable to the JSON It says:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meanings' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload."

Here is the code:

```
    // Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidluzgouveia/kanji-data/master/kanji-jouyou.json', true)

request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
var data = JSON.parse(this.response)   
 
 var kanji = document.getElementById("kanji").value;  

 console.log(kanji);
 



 //  document.getElementById("on").innerHTML = data.日.readings_on;   ------ WORKS CORRECTLY
 document.getElementById("reading").innerHTML = data.kanji.meanings; ------ DOESN'T WORK
 document.getElementById("kun").innerHTML = data.kanji.readings_kun; ------ DOESN'T WORK
 document.getElementById("on").innerHTML = data.kanji.readings_on;   ------ DOESN'T WORK
 

 
 **// IF INSTEAD OF kanji I will put something else for example 日 my code works as it should.**

 
 }

request.send();
```

Comment: If you're new to JS, I strongly recommend making sure your tutorial/book is recent (and targets "ES6" or even "ES2018" or up), because `XMLHttpRequest` hasn't been a thing in a long time, it was replaced by the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) many years ago. Similarly, you don't use `.innerHTML = ...` to set text in an HTML element you use `.textContent = ...` - finally, Github makes it very clear that its `raw` view is not a content hosting system: download the files and host them alongside your own HTML/CSS/JS files.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'meanings' of undefined` means that `data.kanji` is `undefined`. And indeed, if you look at the JSON, "kanji" is nowhere to be found. The object does not have a property with that name

Comment: But as for why your code doesn't work: there is no `data.kanji`. If you look at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidluzgouveia/kanji-data/master/kanji-jouyou.json you'll see that each kanji is its own object, so you need to use `data.日.[...]` for each individual kanji. You're already doing that for `readings_on`, why did you change it to `data.kanji` for the other fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). See the example below:

```js
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidluzgouveia/kanji-data/master/kanji-jouyou.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
  
    let kanji = document.getElementById('kanji').value; 
    console.log('Success: ', data[kanji].meanings);
    
    // json data returned, write the rest of your code here
    // ....

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="kanji" value="日" />
```

Comment: still the same problem Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'meanings' of undefined.

Comment: @wisedaimyo please check the edit you can access `meanings`. I used `Object.values`. in my example but i think you don't need that. What is `kenji`?

Comment: My main problem in my code is that when I am adding variable kanji to this : document.getElementById("reading").innerHTML = data.kanji.meanings; It doesn't work but when I add instead of variable kanji real character for example this: 日 my code works totally fine.

Comment: var kanji = document.getElementById("kanji").value; from this is the kanji value.

Comment: @wisedaimyo write it like this `data[kanji].meanings`

Comment: tried now there is another error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '**'

Comment: here is img what it should do: https://ibb.co/gyxmLjh

Comment: @wisedaimyo i edited my answer please check how to get the value from the input and use it.

Comment: @wisedaimyo your mistake was that you assigned the value of the input to variable `kanji` and then tried to use it on the `data` object like this: `data.kanji` which is wrong. In that case you use it like this `data[kanji` since `kanji` is a variable and not a property of the `data` object. This is a property of the `data` object `日`.